# Estimating elasticity of $y$ with respect to $x$ in a log-log specification

Tags: regression, self-study, logarithm, elasticity

[image: The question]

My rudimentary workings so far is that;

$\log(y_i/x_i) = \log(y_i)-\log(x_i)$

Factorise, so, $\log(y_i/x_i) = \log(y_i) + \upsilon_i - \log(\gamma_i + 1)$

Thus, elasticity of $y$ to $x$ is always $>1$.

However I'm not sure if I'm correct.

What is the reasoning behind the full answer to the questions? Solutions with proof would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Since this appears to be an assignment or a practice problem, please add the `self-study` tag and [read its wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Comment: You made an error in factorising. Recall that $\log(y_i) = \beta_0+\beta_1 \log(x_i)+\varepsilon_i$. You need to enter this equation in the right hand side of $\log(y_i/x_i)=\log(y_i)-\log(x_i)$. And then compare it to the equation 0.2.

Comment: Note also the typo in the assigment. The equations are numbered 0.1, 0.2, but they are referred as 1.1 and 1.2. You need to assume that this is a typo, otherwise the assignment is is not coherent. In that case the power lies with the person doing the assignment, i.e. you can say that the problem is stated incorrectly and it should not be graded :)

Comment: Thanks mpiktas - so what would the entire proof for 1a. be, if you could please be kind enough to type it out. And what about 1b and 1c? I have absolutely no idea on those parts. And yes, they should be numbered 1.1 and 1.2, but it was a typo :)

Comment: @tjo, we don't usually go for providing complete solutions around here.  See the `self-study` tag [wiki I linked above](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).  The point is to help you learn and understand the problem, and simply giving you the answer will not do that ;)